# Javascript Regex matching all US date formats

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match the all possible formats in US to the one single regex. Is it possible? How?

Those are the possible formats:

```
2017/09/15
2017.09.15
2017-09-15
09/15/2017
09.15.2017
09-15-2017
9/15/2017
9.15.2017
9-15-2017
2017/9/15
2017-9-15
2017.09.15
```

but I also need these:

```
09/15
09.15
09-15
```

I've tried this `/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-\.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-\.]\d{4}/` but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you include the `javascript` that you have  tried to resolve inquiry at Question?

Comment: "I am trying to match..." where? I don't see javascript code.

Comment: javascript code is not important. I need a regex that will match these cases.

Comment: @HailHydra The OP has now supplied the regex-literal Javascript code being used to create `RexExp` object. (I think from here, you can safely assume it's being passed into a string's `match` method or having its `exec` method called on a string of the form supplied in the list.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, should work: `\d+(\/|\.|-)+.*\d`

Answer (score 1):

This will prove to be a torturous task for a single regex, regardless of the language and flavor, because not only does the mixed ordering demand you have varying length tokens for each of the Y, M, D components, but the *semantics* of each of those components has specific limitations of acceptable values. For example, in the 2 digit first form, which means month first, you cannot have a value greater than 12. But in the 4 digit form, year first, your max value is constrained only by the maximum year you want to support. Then, you've got to consider in the second position if year first, a limit of 12 because month is second, otherwise if month first the limit is 31.

Your posted effort is far from the final answer. I strongly suggest introducing a data sanitization step in something turing-complete that identifies and orders each token based on valid values before continuing down this road. Otherwise, please explain why that's just not an option.

Comment: +1; Also, regexes can't enforce a match between the first and second `[/.-]` separator characters (thereby allowing things like `2017-09.07`), since regular languages can't use a stack to remember the characters. You'd have to explicitly spell out the full form with each matching set of separators and join then with pipes.

Comment: ok I can split it into two regexes. One will match the one part and the other will match the other part.

Comment: I don't think the accepted answer is correct. For example, you will also match "2015-10-23-132", "1-1-whatTheHellIsThisDoingHere132". To quote JWZ, "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems".